# System.CalloutException: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint

Tags: javascript, webservices, httpcalloutmock

[image]Try to do a mock callout internally on custom button click and also added the instance in remote site setting.

```
@future(callout=true)
webservice static void generatePDF(Id idList, String sessionId)
{
    System.debug('OK Its here: '+idList);
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://'+URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost()+'/services/apexrest/createstatusreport/');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody('{"srList":'+JSON.serialize(idList)+'}');
    System.debug(req.getBody());
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ sessionId);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setTimeout(30000);
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res;
    if(!test.isRunningTest()){ 
        res = http.send(req);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @TusharSharma it is working in production, not in the sandbox.  and my remote site setting has the instance url registered

Answer (score 4):

Remote Site Settings are case sensitive with regards to the host name. Typically, this causes issues when you decide to name your sandbox with uppercase letters. There's an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CNviQAG) to have this fixed. It is strongly recommended that you stick to using lowercase letters and numbers only in your Sandbox name to avoid this problem. Accordingly, using the proper capitalization in the endpoint URL should likely fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The remote site setting end URL should be https://informatic--UAT.cs96.my.salesforce.com

Comment: thanks for your reply, the remote site setting end URL is same please find above in the question description.

Comment: Then please check the spelling. its also cause an issue.
In your base URL is https://informatic--UAT.cs96.my.salesforce.com but your remote site setting end URL should be https://informatic--uat.cs96.my.salesforce.com.